# Manage Customer Attributes in Magento 2.2 Backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.0, customer-attribute

As mentioned in the [Magento 2 Dev Docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/attributes-customer.html), there is an admin section to manage customer attributes.

> On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Attributes, choose Customer.

I looked for this section in Magento 2.2 but I did not found it. As i saw, the screenshots in the Dev Docs were made with Magento Version 2.0.0.

Is this admin section still available in Magento 2.2, and where can it be found, or is there a new way to manage your customer attribtues?

I would need this to edit an existing customer attribute and add a new one for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer Attributes are only manageable via backend in Magento EE, and you linked the EE docs, if you are using Magento CE you have to edit/add customer attributes programmatically.

Comment: Oh man, didn't see that this was the ee docs... Thank you anyway :-)